# what is the <my_namespace> in the command ic build -t registry.ng.bluemix.net/<my_namespace>/myimage

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to build a docker image at bluemix and the documentation shows this command example

`ic build -t registry.ng.bluemix.net/<my_namespace>/myimage .`

At this page:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_cfic.html#container_cli_reference_cfic__build

What is the `<my_namespace>`  in the command example ?

How can I confirm the right value to put there ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your organization has not yet set a namespace for containers, you can do so with the following command:

```
cf ic namespace set container-namespace
```

This will set the namespace for your organization to "container-namespace". If you are unsure if your organization has a namespace set already, you can check this with the following command:

```
cf ic namespace get
```

This will show you what value should be placed where you see `<my_namespace>`.